# Functional and Performance testing on applications built on kafka, elastic search and kibana

Tags: testing, elasticsearch, automation, apache-kafka, kibana-4

I am working on a system where stream of data(real time data) is pushed to kafka cluster and then to elastic search and displayed through kibana.

Do i need to testing on the kafka cluster, testing on elastic search cluster separately?. I am confused how to go with exact testing approach for this.

Could someone help me to do testing approach for functional and performance testing on the applications built on this stack and are there are any tools that helps to do.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the scope of the tests? Which question do you want to have answered with your tests?

Comment: The scope of the tests are to perform the functional testing and performance testing on the complete system. How do i check the latency and the response time on the complete system.

Comment: Our system accepts the gzip form of binary data from the other system and processes the data and displaying in the kibana by using the kakfa system and elastic search.The scope of the tests are to perform the functional testing and performance testing on the complete system. The questions that tests needs to answer is to verify that the data that is pushed to the kafka system is present in the kafka topics created and to verify the data is present in the correct indices of the elastic search.

Comment: Next scope of the testing to get the latency(I mean what is the time taken when data is pushed to kakfa and to elastic search).
 How to measure performance metrics on the system if the system is receiving the 1000's of messages which go thru kakfa and elastic and to kibana.

Comment: "The scope of the tests are to perform the functional testing and performance testing on the complete system" That should answer your question regarding what you should include. (Everything)

Comment: Yes Jens, Thanks for your reply. I am wandering how to approach for 
 performance testing. how do i check performance on the kafka systems and elastic search.

Comment: Maybe you shoult thing about which question you want to anwer, when you do performance tests. To test something you need some requirements test against it.

Answer (score 0):

These make sense to me and I have executed few similar scenarios for these asks.

1. You can measure the performance of the Elasticsearch Cluster when 1 or multiple nodes in the cluster goes down. This will also help in validating the configuration of the Cluster.
2. Benchmarking the time taken by the query from Kibana Dashboard to fetch query from the ES Cluster for different Data load and varying shards per index
3. Depending on the type of processing of data that you do, you can comeup with multiple Scenarios